# How to: keep key in dict for further use after random.choice? invert keys with values as for switching languages in a translator?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

Premise: I'm a newbie, so stay aware!

First of all the code which I have some issues with:

```
import random
import time

vocabulary = {
    'hola':'hello',
    'adiós':'bye',
    'noche':'night',
    'pronto':'soon'
}

def spa_to_eng():
    already_used = []
    total_attempts = 0
    while len(already_used) < len(vocabulary):
        spa_to_eng = list(vocabulary.keys())
        for key in spa_to_eng:
            key = random.choice(spa_to_eng)
            if key not in already_used:
                print("word to translate:",key)
                answer = input("enter translation: ")
                if answer == vocabulary[key]:
                    print("RIGHT!\n")
                    total_attempts = total_attempts + 1
                    already_used = already_used + [key]
                else:
                    print("NOPE! The right answer is",vocabulary[key].upper(),"\n")
                    total_attempts = total_attempts + 1
                time.sleep(1.5)
            else:
                continue
        break
    print(len(vocabulary),"words done in",total_attempts,"total attempts.")
    print("Effectiveness:",str(int(len(vocabulary)/total_attempts*100))+"%")

spa_to_eng()
```

Now both issues I´d like to find the solution to:

1) My purpose is to break and print the final result after having guessed all words that actually are in the dictionary (vocabulary). However, code stops sometimes after 2, other times 3 or 4 attempts. Instead, by the end of the run I should have completed 4 words, or whatever their quantity is (that's the reason of "while len(already_used) < len(vocabulary):"), in an unknown number of attempts depending on my ability. While simulating it on pythontutor.com it seems like the code jumps into the dictionary switching from key to key and marking some keys as already chosen, therefore it stops after 2 to 4 attempts refusing to use them once again. In short: if I guess the word, this shouldn't be used in further questions; if do not guess, it should be asked again and again til I finally write its correct translation.

2) Is there a short way to invert the order of keys and values? Would like to have to change close to nothing in order to be able to translate from English to Spanish, instead of Spanish to English.

Sorry for the lenght, many thanks if somebody helps. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def spa_to_eng():
    already_used = []
    total_attempts = 0
    spa_to_eng = list(vocabulary.keys())
    while len(already_used) < len(vocabulary):
        key = random.choice(spa_to_eng)
        if key not in already_used:
            print("word to translate:",key)
            answer = raw_input("enter translation: ")
            if answer == vocabulary[key]:
                print("RIGHT!\n")
                total_attempts = total_attempts + 1
                already_used = already_used + [key]
                spa_to_eng.remove(key)
            else:
                print("NOPE! The right answer is",vocabulary[key].upper(),"\n")
                total_attempts = total_attempts + 1
            time.sleep(1.5)
        else:
            continue
    print(len(vocabulary),"words done in",total_attempts,"total attempts.")
    print("Effectiveness:",str(int(float(len(vocabulary))/total_attempts*100))+"%")
```

moved `spa_to_eng` outside while loop and removed unnecessary for loop, can you try above snippet of code

**for 2nd**

```
rev_vocabulary = {v: k for k, v in vocabulary.iteritems()}
```

Comment: AWESOME!! Exactly what I expected, many thanks for it!! Only needed to cut "raw_" from your edit as my version merely asks for "input". Everything works :) would you have a solution to my second problem as well?

Comment: Where to insert this line? Do I need then to change all "vocabulary" in "rev_vocabulary"?

Comment: use it after declaring `vocabulary`, like `vocabulary = {v: k for k, v in vocabulary.iteritems()}`, then you don't have to rename.

Comment: That works ;) thanks again, already clicked on the arrow up after your first comment, but have rep < 15, it's registered as pending.

Comment: Yeah that's right, noticed the button right now. Done ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're initializing your list of words `spa_to_eng` **inside** your main loop, so every time you call `random.choice(spa_to_eng)` it has a complete vocabulary to choose from. You should initialize the list before entering the `while` loop, then remove words that were correctly guessed from the list rather than appending them to a separate list.

Comment: Yeah it was the first step toward the desired result, anyway dzięki za odpowiedź. :D